# Ubuntu 14.04 (cinnamon desktop) freezing, typically when using terminal

Tags: unity, command-line, 14.04, freeze, cinnamon

This is really strange, but frequently, Ubuntu freezes when I'm trying to enter (even basic) commands in the terminal. It does randomly happen when opening programs like Chrome as well. It freezes for anywhere between 1 to 10 minutes, and during that time I can move my cursor but nothing else. I just recently switched from Unity to the Cinnamon desktop environment and I think that may be the source of the issue, but I haven't found anyone else with the same setup having this problem. At first it was just an occasional annoyance, but it's really beginning to interfere with my work (I'm typing this in Windows). I would really appreciate any insight anyone may have, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some problem with `unity` and `cinnamon` sharing but modifying libraries and messing each other up. If you have the patience necessary I recommend uninstalling both by running `sudo apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoremove`, then rebooting into a text console and installing just `cinnamon`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sbergeron's answer, I fixed this by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity
sudo apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, please if you think that you can help providing information of the problem, this is the right place:

https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3275